# Quantifying agreement of ordinally ranked sequences

Tags: ordinal-data, ranking, agreement-statistics, kendall-tau, ranks

I've been using a very particular set of closely related metrics to quantify how well two ranked sequences agree with one another. I'd like to know if this way of thinking is well-known and if any of these metrics have a name.

The basic idea is, suppose we have some set of $N$ elements, and we have two different ways to rank them. Typically, we will interpret one of these as a "ground truth" ranking, and another one as an "estimated" ranking. We would like that if we are presented with the top 10, for instance, of the "estimated" ranking, that it has most of the same elements as the top 10 of the "true" ranking. We would also like that if something important in the true top 10 isn't there in the estimated top 10, that it appears relatively quickly thereafter (perhaps in the top 15 or 20), and vice versa. We would like this property to also hold for the top 20, 50, 100, etc.

Mathematically, the basic idea is for each $n$, we take the true top $n$ elements, and look at how far into the estimated rankings you need to go before all of them appear. This gives a sequence of values for each $n$. This sequence ignores false positives, but simply quantifies just how far off the false negatives are. I'll call this $S_{-}$.

We also do the same, but starting with the estimated top $n$ and looking at how far into the true rankings you need to go before they all appear, this time giving a sequence which quantifies how far off the false positives are. I'll call this $S_{+}$.

These sequences give the false negative and false positive scores for each choice of $n$, and there are all kinds of variations on how you can take these to derive some kind of average general score for the entire list. You can normalize by $n$ in various ways and then take various means, medians, extreme values, and so on. There are also various ways to combine the two sequences into one sequence that quantifies both false positives and false negatives (take the max of both, or the mean of both, etc). I view these variations as generally unimportant and am basically happy to use any way of doing this which is some well-known, standardized metric.

**My question:** is there *any* standardized metric, something well-known and with a name, that proceeds along this kind of derivation? It seems a bit different from Kendall's tau and Spearman's rho -- in fact, I can't seem to figure out how to derive those from any obvious metric on these sequences -- but also it's very useful. It gives a way to see how well the top $n$ estimated elements give you a correct view of the top $n$ true elements, which is slightly different.

Seems possibly related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114520/metrics-for-comparing-estimated-lists-to-a-true-list), except that in this situation I feel like I already have a good idea of how to quantify the property I'm after and am mostly looking for if it (or something similar) has a name.

Comment: There's a whole field of ranking metrics like this. NDCG, MRR etc.. They can be taken @5,10,15 etc.. That's what you're looking for.